# Accessing value from one class using protocol in other class IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, protocols

Hello I am trying to access the variables and function from the class which is following one protocol ios swift in other class please let me know what i am doing wrong.
First image is of protocol and class which is declaring variables and functions and second image is of accessing the protocol, force unwrapping it and accessing values,functions.

**code of protocol and first class**

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import Contacts

protocol FilterSessionPresenter: class {
    var numberOfSection: Int {get}
    func viewLoaded()
    func filterTapped()
}

class FilterSessionPresenterImplementation : FilterSessionPresenter {
    init() {
        print("runnninggg...")
    }
    func viewLoaded() {
        print("Hello")}
    func filterTapped() {
        print("Hello")}
    var numberOfSection: Int {
       return 200}
}
```

**code for accessing class**

```
import UIKit

class FilterSessionVC: UIViewController {
    
    var presenter : FilterSessionPresenter!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(presenter.numberOfSection)
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you connecting the 2 classes? When you have a `protocol` inside a variable, you make that variable weak: `weak var presenter : FilterSessionPresenter!`. Replace `protocol FilterSessionPresenter: class {` with `protocol FilterSessionPresenter: AnyObject {` since class is deprecated.

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter actually i am setting value in class and trying to access it i've done the changes you suggest but still the same error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Are you assigning the value of presenter to be an instance of FilterSessionPresenterImplementation?

Comment: That is because `var presenter : FilterSessionPresenter!` is nil when you are trying to access it so this problem has nothing to do with a protocol.

Comment: I want to access the variable numofsection through protocol. Actually i have been assigned they are using same technique and defining protocol inheriting the protocol in one class and defining all its functions and variables then access it in other class by making or defining the instance like this var presenter : FilterSessionPresenter! in other class i dont know their code is working absolutely fine but mine giving this error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how can i assign it value before it is called?

Comment: Using `prepareForSegue(segue:, sender:)` I assume or your storyboard.

Comment: yes you are right i have tried to copy from other file but still getiing error can you please review it what i am doing wrong now thank you.

Comment: @IBAction func filterBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "FilterSessionsVC", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "FilterSessionsVC", let navigation = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let vc = navigation.topViewController as? FilterSessionVC {
            vc.presenter = FilterSessionPresenterImplementation()
        }
    }

Comment: You have quite a chain of optional unwraps there. Chances are that something isn't what you expect and so the `if` is skipping the assignment. Set a breakpoint and use the debugger

Comment: FilterSessionPresenterImplementation is not initializing don't know whats the issue